# How to automatically launch LibreWolf browser in full screen?

Tags: firefox, browser

When I launch the LibreWolf browser it opens in a small window:

[image]

Then I manually expand the window to full screen:

[image]

It is inconvenient for me to open the window in full screen manually after every time I start the LibreWolf.

I think I need to change some setting somewhere in the `about:config` section, but I don’t know which setting.

**Update:** I use Xorg + Arch + LibreWolf 87 (based on Firefox 87).

Comment: The size and placement of windows on your screen is usually the responsibility of the `window manager` rather than the program itself. So you should be telling us which window manager you are using. Most X programs have a `-geometry=600x800+50+100` option. See https://www.x.org/releases/X11R6.7.0/doc/X.7.html#sect6

Comment: about:config
set privacy.resistFingerprinting to false

maybe the next entry also

Comment: Changing option `privacy.resistFingerprinting` in `about:config` is helped. Only I do not know how it is to reduce my privacy when visiting sites.

Comment: "Xorg+Arch" still doesn't tell us what window manager you are using. Now you have told us Arch, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/window_manager

Comment: I apologize. I use latest version of GNOME 3. When I run command `wmctrl -m` i get: `GNOME Shell`, and when I run `env | grep -i gdmsession` I get: `GDMSESSION=gnome`.